# image set of the flattening

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Find the equation of the line that is the image set of the flattening
$$f(x,y)=(3x-3y, x-y).$$

Could somebody tell me where I need to start as haven't got a clue?

Comment: A line is given by 2 points...

Comment: What is flattening?

Comment: By inspection, $t\cdot(3,1)$.